# Logic For Delete Statement With Subquery

Tags: mysql

So I have 2 table like below

```
MariaDB [multiple_join]> select*from orders;
+---------+------------+------------+--------------+------------+
| orderId | customerid | ordertotal | discountrate | orderdate  |
+---------+------------+------------+--------------+------------+
|       1 |          3 |    1910.64 |         5.49 | 2019-12-03 |
|       2 |          4 |     150.89 |        15.33 | 2019-06-11 |
|       3 |          5 |     912.55 |        13.74 | 2019-09-15 |
|       4 |          7 |     418.24 |        14.53 | 2019-05-28 |
|       5 |         55 |     512.55 |        13.74 | 2019-06-15 |
|       6 |         57 |     118.24 |        14.53 | 2019-12-28 |
+---------+------------+------------+--------------+------------+
6 rows in set (0.349 sec)

MariaDB [multiple_join]> select*from neworders;
+---------+------------+------------+--------------+------------+
| orderId | customerid | ordertotal | discountrate | orderdate  |
+---------+------------+------------+--------------+------------+
|       1 |          3 |    1910.64 |         5.49 | 2019-12-03 |
|       2 |          4 |     150.89 |        15.33 | 2019-06-11 |
|       3 |          5 |     912.55 |        13.74 | 2019-09-15 |
|       4 |          7 |     418.24 |        14.53 | 2019-05-28 |
|       5 |         55 |     512.55 |        13.74 | 2019-06-15 |
|       7 |         57 |     118.24 |        14.53 | 2019-12-28 |
+---------+------------+------------+--------------+------------+
6 rows in set (0.047 sec)
```

And here's my syntax for delete statement

```
delete from neworders where ordertotal<select max(ordertotal) from orders);
```

And here's the result

```
+---------+------------+------------+--------------+------------+
| orderId | customerid | ordertotal | discountrate | orderdate  |
+---------+------------+------------+--------------+------------+
|       1 |         3  |     1910.64|        5.49  | 2019-12-03 |
+---------+------------+------------+--------------+------------+
```

So what I confused is why ordertotal from neworders table appeared with 1910.64 result? I mean isn't the same as the max of ordertotal from orders? And I'm using (<) not (<=) so it supposedly not included, right?

Comment: If the value `1910.64` is not an exact type, then this value as it appears in the two tables may not actually be the same.  Read about floating point arithmetic to better understand this.  And maybe the `ordertotal` column should be `NUMERIC` or `DECIMAL`.

Comment: I'm using int for both

Comment: Integer datatype is exact.

Comment: @Akina Maybe, but dividing an integer by another integer might result in an inexact float result.

Comment: Any datatype division may produce floating-point result (until the division is not integer one - DIV operator).

Comment: Maybe it's too early for me or there are some deleted comments, but "1910.64" cannot be an integer, so I am not sure what *I'm using int for both* refers to (it looks as if it refers to the datatype of ordertotal). Also, I am not sure what your original problem is: you delete all rows with a value < 1910.64 and are wondering why a row that is not smaller than 1910.64 (but equal to it) is not deleted? Again, maybe I am missing something here...